# close tab when a new site has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I am wondering whether it's possible to close a tab as soon as a new site has loaded, without having to use js on the new site. I basically want to close the tab when we receive any content from the new site.

I use this to trigger a click event which submits a form:

```
$('#target_attack').click();
```

I tried putting `window.close()` right after this, but the tab closed without having loaded the new site.

I also tried to pause the script for 3 seconds and then close the tab, but for some reasons the site then won't load.

I also thought about using sessions but this means I would have to use js on the other site too, which I want to avoid.

I hope you guys can help a little javascript noob C:
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you are using window.open to open it in a new tab.

```
var winPop = window.open(url);
$(winPop.document).ready(function() {
    window.close();
});
```

Comment: No, I am not opening a new tab. ohhh nvm I just unterstood what you meant :) not sure whether that works tho, as I am submitting a form. I will try it!

Comment: If you are submitting a form, why is it opening in the new window if you want to replace it? Just submit to the same window!

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing

Comment: hey, just wanted to let you know that I am using your method now, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

[If javascript didn't open the window, javascript cannot close the window](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183697#c3). Otherwise, `window.close()` is what you use.

You can try to bypass this security restriction (bad plan), but I do not believe this works on newer versions of any browser:

```
window.top.opener=null;
window.close();
```

See the docs - Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:window.close, IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536367%28VS.85%29.aspx